# Recursively delete files except some in variable root folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im looking for code change to be able to run this in any folder and recursively (any subfolders) without the need to edit the rootdir in the script. Any idea? Thank you

```
@echo off
set ROOTDIR=E:\Testdel\
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir %ROOTDIR% /s /b /a-d ^|findstr /vile ".xls .xlt .xlm .xlsx .xlsm .xltx .xltm .ppt .pot .pps .pptx .pptm .potx .ppam .ppsx .sldx .sldm .pdf .xls .doc .dot .docx .html .docm .dotb .docb .tiff .jpg .png .cdr .cpt .psd"') do del "%%F"
```

Comment: Are you expecting somebody here to change youe code for you? This site does not work like that, we expect you to write your own code, we only help you to fix a problem with the code you have written and submitted. You are not new to this site, so should, by now, have taken the [tour] and read through [ask]. Please attempt the task yourself, and if it fails to do what it was written to do, and as intended, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your failing code, along with sufficient information for us to reproduce the issue you're experiencing. Thank you.

Comment: Code is not mine, found it here in two cases, have left a comment there with the question and got no reply. And yes, I have tried for 2 hours to make it run without luck, so what is the point to write it here when its not working, rather to ask directly someone who can see the solution right away. Would not bother stack overflow with working code.

Comment: Well if you don't provide the code which is not working, how are we supposed to help you to fix it? As I said, this site helps you to fix a fully explained and reproducible issue with your submitted code, it does not provide you with code, to add to somebody elses, and for which you've not demonstrated any attempt at solving yourself. All you need to do is to [edit] your question to include your attempt, and explain to us exactly what the issue is it is exhibiting. Perhaps you should research what `%CD%`, `%__CD__%`, `%0`, and `%1` mean, then try to incorporate one or other of those.

Comment: Based on what you are describing all you need to do is remove any reference to the %rootdir% variable within the code.   Then place the batch file in the folder you want to process and execute the .BAT file.

Comment: This is not funny, I would bet my life that I tried that the way you say and guess what, now its working. I could break something right now. Thank you....I just can not believe it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed like this thanks to Squashman:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /s /b /a-d ^|findstr /vile ".xls .xlt .xlm .xlsx .xlsm .xltx .xltm .ppt .pot .pps .pptx .pptm .potx .ppam .ppsx .sldx .sldm .pdf .xls .doc .dot .docx .html .docm .dotb .docb .tiff .jpg .png .cdr .cpt .psd"') do del "%%F"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).